# Checking a very big tab separated file for unique values

Tags: r, tabs

I have a very large report file, and I want to check a certain column called `Sample_id`, for unique values. My data looks as follows:

```
 [1] "[Header]"                                                                               
 [2] "GSGT Version\t1.9.4"                                                                     
 [3] "Processing Date\t7/6/2012 11:41 AM"                                                      
 [4] "Content\t\tGS0005701-OPA.opa\tGS0005702-OPA.opa\tGS0005703-OPA.opa\tGS0005704-OPA.opa"       
 [5] "Num SNPs\t5858"                                                                          
 [6] "Total SNPs\t5858"                                                                        
 [7] "Num Samples\t132"                                                                        
 [8] "Total Samples\t132"                                                                      
 [9] "[Data]"                                                                                 
[10] "SNP Name\tSample ID\tGC Score\tAllele1 - AB\tAllele2 - AB\tChr\tPosition\tGT Score\tX Raw\tY Raw"
[11] "rs1867749\t106N\t0.8333\tB\tB\t2\t120109057\t0.8333\t301\t378"                                   
[12] "rs1397354\t106N\t0.6461\tA\tB\t2\t215118936\t0.6461\t341\t192"                                   
[13] "rs2840531\t106N\t0.5922\tB\tB\t1\t2155821\t0.6091\t296\t391"                                     
[14] "rs649593\t106N\t0.8709\tA\tB\t1\t37635225\t0.8709\t357\t200"                                     
[15] "rs1517342\t106N\t0.4839\tA\tB\t2\t169218217\t0.4839\t316\t210"                                   
[16] "rs1517343\t106N\t0.5980\tA\tB\t2\t169218519\t0.5980\t312\t165"                                   
[17] "rs1868071\t106N\t0.5518\tA\tB\t2\t30219358\t0.5518\t355\t229"                                    
[18] "rs761162\t106N\t0.6923\tA\tB\t1\t13733834\t0.6923\t315\t257"                                     
[19] "rs911903\t106N\t0.6053\tA\tA\t1\t46982589\t0.6096\t383\t158"                                     
[20] "rs753646\t106N\t0.6676\tA\tB\t1\t208765509\t0.6688\t341\t169"
```

So my question is how to check the column `Sample_ID` for unique values with R. I already know its something with `unique` but how to take the right column with tab separated files?

Comment: Could you post the output of dput() on the character vector next time. I eventually got a faithful copy but it was a bit of a hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first read the file:

```
sample_data <- read.table(file = "filename", sep = "\t", skip = 9, header = TRUE)
```

then do (spaces in the column names were automatically converted to dots)

```
unique(sample_data[, "Sample.ID"])
```

Comment: Correct except for the field name. Should be either the column number or "Sample.ID". By default, R changes the names of improperly named columns during input with the read.table and derivative functions. See ?make.names for the details.

Comment: Thanks for the nice and fast answer !

Comment: I just tested it and find another needed correction. Also need to add header=TRUE

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in an R object, say it's named "Lines", then you would need to apply the sensible solution offered by cafe876 to a textConnection call or use the text= argument which was added to R in recent versions:

```
samp_dat <-  read.table(file = textConnection(Lines), sep = "\t", skip = 9, header=TRUE)
```

OR:

samp_dat <-  read.table(text= Lines, sep = "\t", skip = 9, header=TRUE)

Here's a test case:

```
Lines <-
c("[Header]                                                                               ", 
"GSGT Version\t1.9.4                                                                     ", 
"Processing Date\t7/6/2012 11:41 AM                                                      ", 
"Content\t\tGS0005701-OPA.opa\tGS0005702-OPA.opa\tGS0005703-OPA.opa\tGS0005704-OPA.opa       ", 
"Num SNPs\t5858                                                                          ", 
"Total SNPs\t5858                                                                        ", 
"Num Samples\t132                                                                        ", 
"Total Samples\t132                                                                      ", 
"[Data]                                                                                 ", 
"SNP Name\tSample ID\tGC Score\tAllele1 - AB\tAllele2 - AB\tChr\tPosition\tGT Score\tX Raw\tY Raw", 
"rs1867749\t106N\t0.8333\tB\tB\t2\t120109057\t0.8333\t301\t378                                   ", 
"rs1397354\t106N\t0.6461\tA\tB\t2\t215118936\t0.6461\t341\t192                                   ", 
"rs2840531\t106N\t0.5922\tB\tB\t1\t2155821\t0.6091\t296\t391                                     ", 
"rs649593\t106N\t0.8709\tA\tB\t1\t37635225\t0.8709\t357\t200"
)
```